# Modify element in an angularjs directive and reinject it in a template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to apply conditional modification to an element with a directive attached to it and then put in in a new template. I don't want to 'override' it.

I haven't figured it out yet, thanks btw!

I know I can use translude, but I would like to be able to modify conditionally the template too.

html:

```
<directive-name></directive-name>
```

js:

```
.directive('directiveName', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link : {
      pre: function(scope, iElement, iAttributes) {
        if(condition) {
          iElement.attr('a-attribute', "field")
          break;
        }
        else {
          iElement.attr('b-attribute', "field")                     
          break;
        }
        var template =
          '<pre>' + // Some very cool template here
            iElement.html() + // Here it's where it doesn't work :(
          '</pre>';
        newElement = $compile(template)(scope);
        iElement.replaceWith(newElement);     
       }
     },
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
.directive('nsDirective', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        controller: 'nsDirectiveCtrl',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
            var build = function () {
                var html = '';
                if (attributes.type === 'a') {
                    html = '<div ns-directive-a></div>';
                }
                element.empty().append($compile(html)(scope));
            };
            // Init
            build();
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Cory, but I need to keep the original element in case they are some other attributes added to it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

I needed iElement[0].outerHTML!

```
'<pre>' + // Some very cool template here
  iElement[0].outerHTML
'</pre>';
```